# SQL Server 2012 - Linked Server to SQL Server 2000

Tags: msdtc, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to use the SQLNCLI 10 driver to set up a Linked Server to a legacy SQL Server 2000 instance on our network.

I understand you cannot use Version 11 as it doesn't support SQL Server 2000 (running on Windows 2003 latest service packs). The SQL Server 2012 is on Windows 2008 x64.

I can create the conenction, and the databases and their schemas display, but when I try to execute a query I get:

> Msg 8522, Level 16, State 3, Line 1 Microsoft Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator (MS DTC) has stopped this transaction.

Anyone seen this or know how to resolve it?

Comment: Have you configured MS DTC on both servers?

Comment: Yes. I've tried altering the security settings - no joy

Comment: Can you run a simple transaction as a distributed transaction?

Comment: This appears to be a bug in the new version of the driver. You need to wrap the call in an explicit transaction to work around it.

Comment: Be sure to submit the feedback to Microsoft via connect.microsoft.com so that they can address the problem.

Comment: Done : https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/731869/using-sqlncli10-to-create-a-linked-server-to-sql-server-2000-causes-a-fault